# Which plume is which?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

One day, at the spirits' bathhouse you work at, you encounter 5 dragons, who have decided to share a bath. Due to the lighting you can only see what is above the water, that being 5 tails, and 4 heads (presumably, there is another head beneath the surface).

The 5 tails vary in appearance wildly: One has a single long feather, another is forked, with a pair of feathers side-by-side, another still has a soft fluffy base, the fourth has a feather tipped with a sharp point, and the final tail bears a feather with all the colours of a rainbow. The heads are equally diverse, with the visible heads bearing ornaments as varied as a cockscomb, boar tusks, impressive antlers, or just simple fur.

You need to know which tail belongs to which head, but it would seem rude and foolish to ask outright. At this point, your coworker decided to drop off a few riddles, presumably to help you along.

These riddles are:

- A varied diet can help you stay vibrant
- A long plume is often compensating for something
- Unwanted hair is rarely alone
- Some ungulates can act quite sharp
- Class differences can often fork a group
- The gilled head is a long way down

Using these riddles, work out which tail belongs to which head.

Comment: The combination of [[tag:riddle]] and [[tag:logical-deduction]] seems a bit of an oxymoron - the former is supposed to be used for indirect clues towards a concept and the latter for direct, formal logic.

Comment: @bobble You need to do a logical deduction on the riddles' answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising the information:

1. **tails**

   - a single long feather
   - forked, with a pair of feathers side-by-side
   - a soft fluffy base
   - a feather tipped with a sharp point
   - a feather with all the colours of a rainbow
2. **heads**

   - cockscomb
   - boar tusks
   - impressive antlers
   - simple fur
   - gills

---

*Some ungulates can act quite sharp*

> Antlered creatures such as deer are ungulates, so this presumably means the **sharp-tailed** creature is the one with **antlers**.

*Unwanted hair is rarely alone*

> This indicates that hair comes together: the tail with the **soft fluffy base** belongs with the head of **simple fur**.

*A varied diet can help you stay vibrant*

> Boars are famously omnivorous, so this probably means the creature whose tail has **all the colours of the rainbow** is the one with **boar tusks**.

*Class differences can often fork a group*

> This must refer to the creature with the **forked tail**; I'm not sure why, but "class differences" presumably indicates the **cockscomb** (it's either that or gills, it's all we've got left).

*A long plume is often compensating for something*

> This refers to the tail with a **single long feather**, and maybe "compensating for something" suggests that the **gilled head** is the most boring.

*The gilled head is a long way down*

> This "riddle" is just to tell us the nature of the fifth head.

Comment: I wonder if the last two creatures are flipped as the gilled creature IS alone and in its own class (deep vs shallow)

Comment: @Amoz If we're getting into biological classes, both cocks (Aves) and gilled creatures (probably Osteichthyes) are separate from fur, antlers, etc. (Mammalia).

Comment: Yes that ambiguity is why I wondered if they meant spatial class (location in pool) vs biological class.

Comment: The pointed, rainbow, and forked tails are right, but overall the reasoning isn't correct

Comment: @Randal'Thor "If we're getting into biological classes, both cocks (Aves) and gilled creatures (probably Osteichthyes) are separate from fur, antlers, etc. (Mammalia)" This comment is also on the right lines

Comment: Well if 3/5 are right, by process of elimination.... I guess unwanted hair refers to both fluffy base and furry head.

Comment: @IchthysKing Edited, I think the answers are correct now, but I'm not sure if the reasoning is what you intended?

Comment: So @Ichthys King, what is the correct reasoning?